# ReactJS: Extend, Override CSS class

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to

1. import a style class from a CSS file
2. dynamically extend or override the style
3. Apply the new style to react component.

Pseudocode of what I want to achieve

```
import 'common.css'

function MyComponent() {

    if (somethingHappened) {
        style = extendOverrideStyle(styleClassFromCSS)
    } else {
        style = styleClassFromCSS
    }

    return (
        <SomeComponent className=style />
    )
}
```

How can I do this?

**Update:**
Check my answer in the replies for how I finally did this.

Comment: Why don't you add a class and based on it change the styling?

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new class in your CSS file to override the old CSS.
Then do it as

```
function MyComponent() {
    return (
        <div className={somethingHappened ? 'firstclass overwriteclass' : 
       'firstclass'}>
        <SomeComponent />
      </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set style in Component Directly.
First you need to pass the style as prop to your Component and set style inside that component

```
<SomeComponent prop_class={your_style}/>
```

Inside SomeComponent

```
<div className={this.props.your_style}>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer** (implementation somewhat similar to @Rohan's answer):

The `main` css class is the base style rules and `.main.somethingHappened` extends/overrides it. The `main` css class is applied to `myComponent` initially. When `somethingHappened` is true, apply both css classes `main somethingHappened` to `myComponent`.

mystyle.css

```
.main {
   ...
   margin: 10px;
}

.main.somethingHappened {
   margin: 5px
   padding: 5px;
}
```

myComponent.js
(uses classnames library. check @Rohan's approach to avoid classnames library.)

```
import 'common.css'
import classnames from 'classnames'

function MyComponent() {

    let didItHappen = ...

    return (
        <SomeComponent 
           className={classnames('main', {'somethingHappened': didItHappen})} 
        />
    )
}
```